# Add Condition in Google CP-Sat Solver Or-Tools

Tags: optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I tried the following, which does not seem to work. Any ideas? Appreciate the help.

```
for j in range(anz_current_pruef):
  model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for i in range(anz_current_role)) < 2 if sum(
   planung[(i, j)][t] * x[i][j] for i in range(anz_current_role) for t in
   range(time_step_start, time_step_end + 1)) < 10)
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md

Comment: Does not work in what way? Do you get an unexpected output? An error? Nothing happens at all? Please add more detail so we can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

you have to understand that `sum(...) < 10` will create a python object that represent a constraint for the underlying solver.

When used in the context of `if sum(...) < 10`, it will always evaluate to `True` as the object is not `None`.

For the same reason, using `min()` and `max()` python constructs does not work as they are evaluated before being passed to the model.

As pointed by *Stradivari*, you need to create an intermediate Boolean variable that will be `True` iff the `sum(...) < 10`, then use it as an enforcement literal for the first part of your equation.